# AngularJS ng-repeat without using angular-filter

Tags: angularjs

I am having the below json object and I wanted to display them in the table without using angular-filter. I need to group by classes based on id.

```js
/*Output should be like:
1
  Class1
  Class2
2
  Class5*/

  $scope.classes = [
    {
 id: "1",
 name: "class1"
    },
    {
 id: "1",
 name: "class2"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
     name: "class5"
    }
];
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in classes | groupBy: 'id'">
                            <td>
                                {{key.id}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div ng-repeat=“class in value”>
                                    {{class.name}}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
```

Comment: "I need to group by classes based on id" Can you clarify? I'm confused =\

Comment: Can you please provide expected output for a given input?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `angular-filter`? It is already implemented and tested, so it will work seamlessly with your project. If you don't want to use it because you want to implement your own group by, then you should provide some code, showing your attempt to do this; we aren't going to re-invent the wheel for you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.classes = [
    { id: "1", name: "class1" },
    { id: "1", name: "class2" },
    { id: "2", name: "class5" }
  ];
})
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<table ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>names</td>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in classes | orderBy : 'id'" ng-if='$first || classes[$index - 1].id != item.id'>
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>            
        <div ng-repeat="temp in classes | filter : {id: item.id} : strict">
          {{temp.name}}
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```